Separation of agents from their population
I really need help with a problem of mine. I have a population of 100 agents (cows) and i want to separate the 8 of them at some point at the main.
I create a selectOutput block and after i connect it with a hold block and i set the mode at "Block automatically after N agents" and i set the "N agents for self-block" to 8 and i create an cyclic event to unblock the hold block.


I expected the hold block after the arrival of the 8 agents to block the entrance and the rest of the agents to pass through the selectOutput block but my simulation crashed and said that an agent couldn't leave from the selectOutput block.

Remove the hold and event.
Instead, add a variable of type int, initial value 0.
in the SelectOutput's true exit, write myCounterVar++;
In the SelectOutput's condition, write myCounterVar<7
Now, the first 8 will exit via true, the rest via false

This really helped me! But how can i reset the value to zero after all the agents have past through?

pls always ask new questions in new issues, SOF does not work like a forum. This helps building a knowledge base and future users :)

Please accept my apologies. I am a new user and i am still learning how to use the site.

no problem, happy to help :)
